# Reflect.get() using a proxy = error illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, chromium

I'm trying to log items inserted into localStorage via the dot accessor using Chromium.

But i'm getting this error when using Reflect.get() method.

`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

here's my script

```
const localStorageProxy = new Proxy(localStorage, {
    get(target, name, receiver) {
      // error here
      const value = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);

      if (!['setItem', 'getItem', 'removeItem'].includes(name)) {
        console.log(value);
        console.trace();
      }
      return typeof value === 'function' ?
          value.bind(target) :
          value;
    },
    set(target, name, value, receiver) {
      if (!['setItem', 'getItem', 'removeItem'].includes(name)) {
       console.log(value);
       console.trace();
      }
      if (name === 'setItem') {
        return false;
      }
      // probably an error here too
      return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
    },
  });

  Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
    value: localStorageProxy,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
  });
```

Expected result: window.localStorage.myItem = 'some-value' should log the value and a stack trace

This script is used with Tampermonkey on Chromium v74 (should be fine, supported by Chrome 49 and above).

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox and Brave (Chrome, basically). What browser are you using? You'e tagged [tag:chromium] which suggests it should be working for you as well...

Comment: Chromium v74 (revision id : 638880)

Comment: That's pretty out of date. I just installed and tried Chromium Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) and it works just fine.

Comment: yes I know that's out of date, but I have to test stuff on this version. I thought there's an hacky fix to bypass this :[

Comment: Well, it may not be version-specific (I suggest trying it with the latest to find out). Please also show how you're using `localStorageProxy`.

Comment: I assume at some point you then use `localStorage.getItem` or similar? Your best bet for getting help is always to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I updated my code. I just "overload" the window.localStorage object. Then when scripts are using localStorage.myItem = myValue, im getting the stack trace.